# Can I list Google reviews on website without an oAuth

Tags: google-oauth, google-my-business-api

Some time back I signed up and was granted an Google My Business API

In my Google account, I am listed as a manager for nearly 100 local businesses, all of which I manage websites for.

What I want it to be able to have the Google reviews listed on the home page of each clients' website, in a carousel if you will.

What is confusing me is the tutorials all seem to require an oAuth on the page to pop to grant access.

What am I missing here? Should I not be able to use ajax, make a request, get the reviews in json format, and place on the page without need of an oAuth?

Comment: This question doesn't look to be a good fit for this site. Please checkout  https://developers.google.com/my-business/content/support

Comment: Hi, how to get an account id and location id?